# how to send question to QGIS mailing list

Tags: qgis, error, request, community

I am not sure but everytime I post any question to QGIS mailing list, I get the below message?
Am i doing something wrong?

You are not allowed to post to this mailing list, and your message has
been automatically rejected.  If you think that your messages are
being rejected in error, contact the mailing list owner at
qgis-community-team-owner@lists.osgeo.org.

Comment: Have you contacted the mailing list owner at qgis-community-team-owner@lists.osgeo.org?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about QGIS Mailing List, which isn't within the scope of this site.

Answer (score 4):

You have to subscribe first at the original mailing list:

http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-user

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-community-team/

or whatever list you want to subscribe (full list [here](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/mailinglists.html))

After confirming a response, you can receive and send to the mailing list

- as individual mails or daily extract
- as a newsgroup via gmane using `nntp://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.qgis.user`
- like a forum via [gmane](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.qgis.user) or [nabble](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Quantum-GIS-User-f4125267.html).

Comment: I did registered and even confirmed that as well. But getting teh same message.

Comment: I think this should really be reported to the mailing list owner address. Note that thre are several mailing lists, which need to be subscribed separately. Your error mesaage comes from the Community Team list.